# Use Linklabel image to get onclick event with out any text

Tags: c#, winforms, linklabel

I have an linklabel in C# winforms. It has no text but it has an image as background. Is there any way i can use the image as hyperlink to trigger the onclick event?

I have searched a lot and all i could find was only text manipulations (like put the text to transparent..etc). Is there a way around without actually using text? Also if i can get a tooltip for linklabel.. it will be more helpful.

I hope this question is not too mainstream(i am new to C#).

Comment: You can use `button` with a `image` in it.

Comment: i cant use button ... it will spoil the texture of the form.

Comment: Give `FlatStyle:Flat` to make it look as a `imageLink` or else use `PictureBox`.

Comment: can i display tooltip or atleast catch onmousehover event and change cusror display type??

Comment: yeah sure use `tooltip` tool. You will understand while using it.

Comment: How can i change the cursor into hand style on hovering to picture box...which event (and for what control) should i handle?

Comment: You can use `MouseMove` Event in which use `this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;` If you have more doubts, we can have a chat rather extending this discussion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `button` with a `image` in it and make its properties as `FlatStyle:Flat` to give a look as `ImageLink` or else use `PictureBox` and 
To show Tooltip, you can use `Tooltip` tool which invokes a new property in `button` or `PictureBox`.

Comment: I think making the linkcolor to transparent should also work.